# Properties of the neighborhoods of $0$ in the cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, filters

Let $E$ be a vector space with a non countable number of elements. Define 
$$\mathscr{F}=\{U \subset E:0 \in U \hbox{ and } \#E\setminus U<\infty\}.$$
It's easy to see that $\mathscr{F}$ defines a filter on $E$.

I have already proven that:

- $0 \in U$ for all $U \in \mathscr{F}$;
- There exists $U \in \mathscr{F}$ such that $V+V \not\subset U$ for all $V \in \mathscr{F}$;
- For every $U \in \mathscr{F}$ and for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $\lambda \neq 0$ we have $\lambda U \in \mathscr{F}$

> **My question:** I would like to know if every $U \in \mathscr{F}$ is absorbing and if every $U \in \mathscr{F}$ contains some $V \in \mathscr{F}$ which is balanced.

I tried to work with the set $U=E\setminus\{p\}$ where $p \neq 0$, but I was not able to give a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be a vector space over $\Bbb C$. Let $\Bbb T=\{z\in \mathbb{C} :|z|=1\}$ be the unit circle.

If $V\subset E$ is a balanced set and $p\not\in V$, then $\Bbb T\cdot\{p\}\cap V=\varnothing$. Since $p\ne 0$, a set $\Bbb T\cdot\{p\}$ is infinite, so a set $E\setminus\{p\}\in\mathcal F$ contains no balanced set of $\mathcal F$.

Any set $U\in\mathcal F$ is [absorbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set). Indeed, for any element $x\in E$ a set $\Lambda_x=\{\lambda\in\Bbb C:\lambda x\not\in U\}$ is finite and does not contains zero. It follows that $x\in\alpha U$ for each $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$  with $|\alpha|>\max \{|\lambda|^{-1}:\lambda\in\Lambda_x\}$. Indeed, if $x\not\in \alpha U$ then $\alpha^{-1}x\not\in U$, so $\alpha^{-1}\in \Lambda_x$. Thus $|\alpha^{-1}|\ge \min \{|\lambda|:\lambda\in\Lambda_x\}$, that is $|\alpha|\le \max \{|\lambda|^{-1}:\lambda\in\Lambda_x\}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! I had some doubts. Why if $V\subset E$ is balanced and $p \notin V$, then $V \cap \mathbb{C} \cdot \{p\}=\emptyset$ (It seems that $0\in V \cap \mathbb{C} \cdot \{p\}$, because $\lambda x \in V$ for all $|\lambda|\leq1$, in particular, $\lambda=0$)? I think it should be: "$0\in U \in \mathcal{F}$ is", because every $U\in \mathcal{F}$ contains $0$. I also couldn't understand the conclusion: It follows that $x \in \alpha U$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha|>\max\{|\lambda|^{-1}:\lambda \in \Lambda_x \}$. Could you give some more details? Please.

Comment: Just one more comment.  In the fourth row from the bottom to up I think it should be: Any set $0 \in U \in \mathcal{F}$ and in the last line of the proof: Thus $|\alpha^{-1}|\geq \min\{ |\lambda|: \lambda \in \Lambda_x\}$, so that $|\alpha| \leq \max \{|\lambda|^{-1}: \lambda \in \Lambda_x\}$, a contradiction.

Comment: @VictorHugo Oops, sorry. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @VictorHugo Thanks for the edit and sorry for the misprint.

Comment: You are welcome!